# Where to put common Functions/Constants in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.Net MVC. I have a couple of controllers and models. They all use a set of static functions and constants which I call common code.

In my MVC project I have folders for Controller, models and view etc, 
Where is all the common code supposed to be put ?

Is is OK to create a Common folder and create new class for my static functions and same for global constants ?

Answer (score 1):

If you reuse this common code often across solutions, you might want to consider compiling it into its own class library and simply referencing the assembly.

Another thing you'll want to consider is the nature of the common functions. Are they truly just helper functions (like manipulating strings and stuff like that) or do they make more sense mixed into your business layers?

Basic rule is to keep it organized be consistent. There's no right or wrong way to structure your application...only hundreds of thousands of opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you can create `Helper folder` when you set your extension methods or another common utility.

But for constants suggest you to create `Ressource File`

Remarks : All text , warning or info messages, put theses elements in ressource and don't write in code, for gloabalization need(It's my case on project)

Comment: Why put constants in a resource file? Can you elaborate a little more on that?

Comment: All text messages, put theses elements in ressource and don't write in code, for gloabalization need

Comment: can you elaborate exactly ??